# Is the dot product valid for coordinate vectors of infinite length?

Tags: linear-algebra

On Wikipedia, it says the dot product is valid for "any number of dimensions." Let's call it $n$.

$$u\cdot v = |u||v|\cos(\theta)$$

Is this still true if we let $n$ go to infinity?

EDIT: By coordinate vectors of infinte length, I mean coordinate vectors with infinite terms such as $u = <u_1,u_2,u_3, ...u_n, ...>$

Comment: Yes, but you might have convergence issues.

Comment: Yes, look into $\ell^2$ spaces, or more generally, Hilbert spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Answer (score 2):

First of all the dot product of two vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ is defined by:
$$
  u \cdot v = \sum_i u_i v_i
$$
and the angle $\theta$ is by consequence defined so that
$$
  \cos \theta =  \frac{u\cdot v}{\lvert u\rvert \lvert v\rvert}.
$$

As you can see the dot product can be extended to infinite dimensions if the series
$$
 \sum_i u_i v_i
$$
converges. This is the case, for example, when both $u$ and $v$ satisfy:
$$
  \sum u_i^2 < \infty.
$$
The sequences which satisfy this property are the elements of the space called $\ell^2$.

Comment: Does series convergence imply that all terms can be calculated? Or why is it essential?

Comment: The series is required to converge so that the result of the dot product is a well defined finite real number. It might happen that you cannot compute the sum of a series, for example: 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 ... has not a well defined sum.